# ggplot2: multiple colors in geom_segment

Tags: ggplot2

I am using geom_segment and want to be able to put multiple colors in a segment based upon the dataframe values.  (I'm using hex values for colors - it's very important I put specific colors in these segments).  So for example, I may want one segment to be 40% purple, 30% green, and 30% orange; and another segment to be 80% blue and 20% green.   Is this possible with geom_segment?

Comment: No, but you might enjoy the `geom_link*()` family of functions from {ggforce}: https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/geom_link.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `geom_rect` instead of `geom_segment` and building rectangles for each component color.